# Cant get subprocess.call to execute the command in my python script

Tags: python, linux

Im trying to make a script to run the youtube-dl package in order to extract mp3 from youtube videos directly.

I am able to do it with `os.system()` like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os
#getting the youtube video link
vlink = input('Enter the youtube video link: ')
cmd = "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 " + vlink
os.system(cmd)
```

I want to try to accomplish this using `subprocess.call()` / `subprocess.Popen()`.
I've tried many variants of inputting the arguments in the function but they all return error, hope someone could guide me, thanks!

Comment: did you pass a list of args with subprocess? Also what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you can just use `shlex.split` to split up the arguments:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
subprocess.call(shlex.split("youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 " + vlink))
```

*but*, you also probably don't need it:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
subprocess.call([
    "youtube-dl",
    "--extract-audio",
    "--audio-format",
    "mp3",
    "--audio-quality",
    "0",
    vlink])
```

Note that by default, `subprocess` will bypass your shell, so you might need to specify a specific `env` if you are doing path modifications to your environment in shell configuration files.

Comment: thanks, my problem was i did "--audio-format mp3", "--audio-quality 0" as i thought i have to enclose 1 argument together. separating the 'mp3' and '0' solved the problem!

Comment: @bee3 -- _most_ commandline parsers will also let you write it as `'--audio-format=mp3'`.  Writing it that way can be helpful for code clarity as you keep the values associated with the commandline argument that they belong to.